# iOS5 NSDateFormatter - typo? Can't find it

Tags: ios5, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Been reading a lot a posts on this, but I still can't find what's wrong with the code below. propably some typo. I believe I'm getting "code-blind" ;-) Some help please? Thank's.

Not getting the ACTUAL current date+time, just the dateStr used for dateFormat ("2012-08-10 10:00"), instead of the actual date+time, that would be something like: "2012-09-20 @ 13:24".

```
// Trim the date
NSString *dateStr = @"2012-08-10 10:00";

// Convert string to date object
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

// Convert date object to desired output format
dateFormat.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd '@' HH:mm";
dateStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];

NSLog(@">>> TEST: new dateStr is: %@", dateStr);
// Gives result: ">>> TEST: new dateStr is: 2012-08-10 @ 10:00".
```

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED**
Yeah I was code-blind all right, looking att totally wrong issues... Anyway I solved it, the below does what I wanted. Maybe someone else needs it to;

```
// Trim the date    
NSDate *theDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd '@' HH:mm"];

NSString *playDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: theDate];
NSLog(@">>> TEST: new dateStr is: %@", playDate);
```

// Result = ">>> TEST: new dateStr is: 2012-09-20 @ 14:02"